# What is the best way to create a custom ribbon for an Excel Application

Tags: excel, vba, ribbon

I am trying to work out the best way to create a custom ribbon for my new Excel application that persists for each new version of the workbook.

I have seen two methods:
1. Customize ribbon using Excel Options under the file menu *
2. CustomUIEditor

- I have tried option 1 and successfully created a ribbon that runs my macros, but the next version of the workbook still refers to the macros in the original workbook. So am thinking that I need to use option 2.

So before I dive in: If I use option 2 will each saved version of the workbook (application in my case) refer to the macros in that workbook?

Is option 2 the best way to do this in my case or is there a better option?

Comment: Yes, option 2 is the only practical option.

Comment: The Editor I use is http://www.andypope.info/vba/ribboneditor_2010.htm.  Not sure if it's the best, but works for me.

Comment: Option 2 is the way to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I use option 2 will each saved version of the workbook (application in my case) refer to the macros in that workbook?

Yes, each version will refer to the macros in that workbook.

> Is option 2 the best way to do this in my case or is there a better option?

Try using the [Office RibbonX Editor](https://github.com/fernandreu/office-ribbonx-editor/releases/tag/v1.6) instead.

You can read more about possibles routes on the [Change the Ribbon in Excel 2007 and up](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s2/win001.htm) page.

Comment: Thanks, I will get stuck in

Answer (score -1):

Good afternoon,

The best option is:
File -> Options (at the very bottom) -> Custmize ribbon

The screenshot below shows you all the options available.

[image]

Comment: I have done this successfully, but the next copy of my workbook refers to the macros in the workbook where I first created the the ribbon tab.